# Why does sympy not work in my Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda, sympy

I have a very specific problem, that seems to have started randomly. When using Jupyter Notebook, I cannot get any output that requires sympy. There is no error message, I can import sympy, and I can "run" cells with sympy in it (for example define functions that use sympy commands), but as soon as I ask for an output, everything looks like if there's an endless loop, but there isn't, and Python isn't actually calculating anything (as seen in the task manager).

This is a problem ONLY in Jupyter Notebook, in PyCharm all works fine, even the exact same code.
I have Jupyter and Python (and pycharm) from Anaconda, the latest 64-bit version. When I encountered the problem, I removed all of anaconda and installed it again, but it didn't fix the issue. I installed the exact same anaconda version on another computer, used the exact same file to code, and it worked just fine. I even checked my cpu drivers and if my memory was okay, and there is absolutely nothing pointing towards a problem (and as I said, no error messages anywhere).

I'm utterly confused as to what the problem is. Does anybody know what could cause this and how to solve it?

Thanks in advance.